# Unit Test - Construct URI for local file in project

Tags: c#, unit-testing, uri, .net-4.5, xunit

I have a service which parses JSON from an external API.

This service does the following:

1. Constructs a URI to the API
2. Reads the JSON returned
3. Deserializes into relevant C# objects
4. Maps to my domain entities
5. Saves to database

I'm trying to unit-test steps 1-4 (5 is out of scope for this test).

As such, i don't want to be hitting the web api - rather i have a "sample" JSON file stored locally in my test project.

How can i read this file and construct it into a Uri object?

e.g:

```
var uri = new Uri("myfile.json");
```

I'm getting an error saying "The URI is not well formed".

The file is set to Build Action: Embedded Resource, and Copy to Output Directory: Copy always.

I'm on C# .NET 4.5 (VS 2012), and using XUnit for my tests.

Comment: What about `var uri = new Uri("myfile.json", UriKind.Relative);` ?

Comment: @mikez - get's further (passed the ctor), but all the properties (e.g AbsoluteUri) are null and so it doesn't get very far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the`file:` scheme and the fully qualified path to the output directory, which should be the same as were the test is running from.

```
var fqn = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
var uri = new Uri("file://" + fqn + "/myfile.json");
```

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme for more details.

Comment: How do i get the fqn? The file and the test class is in the same directory. I tried `new Uri("file://myfile.json")`, but i get: `{"The UNC path should be of the form \\\\server\\share."}` when i try and do something with it.

Comment: How about `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location`.

Comment: Hmm..nope. I looked on my file system where that path is, and there is only the DLL and PDB there, no text file.

Comment: If you are using MS UnitTest then decorate unit test method with `[DeploymentItem("myfile.josn")]`.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.deploymentitemattribute(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Sorry, you did say XUnit.  I don't use XUnit but I'm sure there is someway to tell it to copy a file or all files in the bin directory.

Comment: doesn't look like there is a way. well this sucks. :) accepted, since this is a xunit problem and not relevant to this question (your solution works if i hard-code the path)

Answer (score 0):

The hint by @RPM1984 suggests the answer. I just ran into this issue and the following hack did it for me:

```
string fqnModified = "\\" + fqn;
Uri uri = new Uri(fqnModified);
```